# Postgres index with only a single combination of integers

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am working on a system that has to reference data created by another application. The other application database has a table which contains:

```
| contactid | revision | lineno | other data... |
| 12345     | 00       | 01     | other data... |
| 12345     | 00       | 02     | other data... |
| 12345     | 01       | 01     | other data... |
| 12345     | 01       | 02     | other data... |
| 67890     | 00       | 01     | other data... |
| 67890     | 01       | 01     | other data... |
```

The key is on contractid, revision, lineno.  In my system, I can only have one contract active at a time, so if in my table I have

```
| 12345     | 00       | 01     | other data... |
| 12345     | 00       | 02     | other data... |
```

I cannot have the same contractid with a different revision in the table.  What kind of index could I use to enforce this wayward kind of uniqueness.

Comment: Is introducing another table acceptable?

Comment: So you have `T1` that looks like the first table and you're building `T2` which has the same structure as `T1` but you're adding an extra uniqueness constraint?

Comment: why don't you create a compound index of (contactid, revision, lineno) which is unique? something like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tableidx ON table (contactid, revision, lineno);`

Comment: @muistooshort - That is correct.

Comment: @sharez - That does not solve the issue.  If I had say record 1234, 1, 1 I want to be able to have multiple records that have 1234, 1, 1 - but only that records that are 1234, 1, and and lineno.  So I cant have 1234, 2, 1.

Comment: @REDMONKEY sure you can have! This is the whole point of compound indexing. You should not create unique index over any single column but on combination of them. So you could have (1234, 1, 1) and (1234, 2, 1). But in this case you cannot have multiple (1234, 1, 1).

Comment: @sharez - The point is I do not want to be able to have 1234,1 and 1234, 2.  If there is a 1234,1 then only further 1234,1 should be allowed, not 1234,2.  It is odd but that is the effect I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an [exclude constraint.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE)

```
create table my_table(
    contactid int, 
    revision text, 
    lineno text, 
    other_data text,
    exclude using gist (contactid with =, revision with <>)
);
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0ae0fa176904a48b6a7207811730eafa)

The constraint uses btree operators `<>` and `=`, hence [btree_gist extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) has to be installed.

```
create extension if not exists btree_gist;
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I need.  Many thanks.  Ps, this wont work on DbFiddle as it needs btree_gist activated.