# SQL: table constraint to reject rows based on table contents

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres, I am trying to find a way to enforce a special kind of constraint across two columns.

I have a table with this schema (the relevant bits):

```sql
CREATE TABLE resources (
  id         SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
  org_id     INT         NOT NULL,
  source_id  INT         NOT NULL,
  data       JSON        NOT NULL  -- to keep it simple, it could be anything
);
```

Some example data:

```
id    | org_id   | source_id    | data
---------------------------------------
1     | 11       | 1001         | {...}
2     | 22       | 2002         | {...}
3     | 33       | 3003         | {...}
4     | 11       | 1001         | {...}
5     | 11       | 2002         | {...}  -- This should be invalid.
```

Assuming the `data` value of all rows is different, both rows `1` and `4` are valid. They're just different resources linked to the same `org_id` and `source_id`.

However, I never want a `source_id` to be used with different `org_id`s. In the example above, row `5` should be invalid because `source_id = 2002` was already used once with `org_id = 22`, and it should not be possible to use it again with `org_id = 11`.

I know how to achieve this in a query, but it either requires locking, or it requires a multi-step process in application code (which wouldn't be the end of the world). I thought it could be done with an [`EXCLUDE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE), but I'm not sure.

Comment: You don't need to create this contraint artificially. Just promote your database model from 2NF to 3NF and this issue will be gone for good. Currently you have inter-column dependency, and 3NF takes care of that.

Comment: You can find a solution with `exclude` in this answer: [Postgres index with only a single combination of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118472/1995738)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247063/what-does-exclusion-constraint-exclude-using-gist-c-with-mean/51247705 maybe helpful.

Comment: @TheImpaler can you post that as an answer, with more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```sql
CREATE TABLE resources (
  id         SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
  org_id     INT         NOT NULL,
  source_id  INT         NOT NULL,
  data       JSON        NOT NULL,
  EXCLUDE USING gist
  (org_id WITH =,
  source_id WITH <>)
);
```

It works correctly with your example:
[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d6349ddf2ca8fde21b1fa9248dedaba4)

Explanation of `<>` operator is [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/postgresql-development-essentials/9781783989003/ch06s03.html)

Example usage of `=` and `<>` operators is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/btree-gist.html#:%7E:text=F.5.1.%20Example%20Usage)

Answer (score 1):

You current database model is in 2NF. To promote it 3NF you need to break the table in two tables as explained in [Third normal form -- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

To promote it to 3NF you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE organization (
  org_id     INT         PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  source_id  INT         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE resources (
  id         SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
  org_id     INT         NOT NULL REFERENCES organization (org_id)
  data       JSON        NOT NULL
);
```

This way the table `resources` won't include values for the column `source_id` anymore, and there won't be any possibility of producing inconsistent data whatsoever. Now, `source_id` will safely live in the table `organization` instead, where only a single value per organization is possible.

As you see, this is a structural solution that is also quite clean.

Comment: @tompave I would like to ask you about your gut reaction to this solution. Is it something you consider good, just decent, or maybe totally unrealistic to your reality? Please comment. No need to respond in an elaborate way but I want your feeback on this.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can see how it would help with the example in my question, but unfortunately I cannot change the DB schema that much. In my case, `org_id` and `souce_id` are not FKs to other tables in the dame DB, and they're just references to some remote resources. I named them `*_id` just to keep the example simple, but now I see how that was misleading, sorry. I suppose that I could add a minimal `organizations` table like how you're showing me, but as I said I'm not sure I can change the schema that much.